# Receiving Error: Invalid hook call in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple component and publish it to npm. Before publishing, I want to test the component out; however, whenever I consume my component in my test application, I'm getting the following: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Here is the offending component:

MyComponent.tsx:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrement = () => setCount(count - 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre></pre>
      <button onClick={increment} name='test1'>
        Increment
      </button>
      <button onClick={decrement} name='test2'>
        Decrement
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

index.ts:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

import './index.css';

export { MyComponent };
```

And this is the test application:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { MyComponent } from 'one-select';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`MyComponent` is imported into the test app via `npm install /path/to/mycomponent-project`

I've created other react apps before (but not a stand-alone component) and I've never had this issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding an unused parameter, `const MyComponent = (_props: any) `.  I think that error is detected by examining the stack so that might make it go away.

Comment: I believe that same error [can come from a variety of sources.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Comment: Thanks @OliverRadini. That link lead me to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435587809) which solved my issue. Unfortunately, however, this required me to eject my test CRA app to edit the webpack config. If anybody has a solution to this that doesn't involve that ejection, I'd be grateful to hear about it.